# Why Clipboard.Clear() not working in WPF, is that due to CriticalSecurity Attibute?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am trying to clean computer clipboard from my WPF application. Code is as follow:-

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Clipboard.Clear();
                    });
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }
        }
```

But clear function is not working, this causes no exception or any error. I guess this is because of **[SecurityCritical] Attribute** on Clear method. Please help me with this stuck here.

[image: This is image of Clipboard class assembly]

Comment: Why running it on a different thread?

Comment: Because it is mentioned in msdn document that it required STA Thread, i tried without Thread but no luck..

Comment: @LegacyCode you don't need seprate thread . Just use `Clipboard.Clear();` it should work fine ! That doc you saw is for `WinForm` i guess.

Comment: What makes you think the function is not working?

Comment: @mm8 i am not able to clear clipboard history, yes i am able to set new text in clipboard, so wondering about the issue, and one more think  i would like to add it is also not working in my windows application too..

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done on a thread that has the right security context, probably that of the user who started the app.

When you use `new Thread` this thread won't be.

To do this you can use `RunImpersonated` as below:

```cs
                WindowsIdentity currentId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                Thread thread = new Thread(
                    () =>
                    {
                        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(currentId.AccessToken, () => {
                            Clipboard.Clear();
                        });
                    });
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
```